# Getting error while creating logic app connection through Bicep

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-logic-app-standard

I am trying to create logicapp api connnection for service bus using Bicep,  below is the bicep code.

```
resource ServicebusApiCon 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: 'servicebus123'
  location: Location
  kind: 'V2'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'servicebus'
    api: {
      name: 'servicebus'
      id: '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${Location}/managedApis/servicebus'
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
      parameterValueSet: {
        name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
        values: {
          namespaceEndpoint: {
            value: 'https://servicebus.servicebus.windows.net:443/'
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

```
for storage account:
 parameterValueSet: {
    name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
    values: {
      accountName: 'storageaccountname'
       
    }
  }
 for keyvault:
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        vaultName: 'keyvaultname'
       
    }     
  
}
```

I am getting below error while deploying it. could you please someone help me if something is missing or wrong ?

```
   **{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource 
   deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
   https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details": 
   [{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": 
   \"InvalidRequestContent\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The request content is not valid and could 
    not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'parameterValueSet' on object of type 
    'ManagedApiReference'. Path 'parameterValueSet', line 1, position 258.'.\"\r\n  
     }\r\n}"}]}}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `api-version` should be **2018-07-01-preview** :

```bicep
resource servicebusConnector 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'servicebus123'
  location: location
  kind: 'V2'
  properties: {    
    api: {
      id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', location, 'servicebus')
    }
    displayName: 'servicebus'
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        namespaceEndpoint: {
          value: 'sb://${servicebusName}.servicebus.windows.net/'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,  i donot see these api version on MSFT website
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections?tabs=bicep

Comment: Yeah it is not referenced but it works.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas, you are super awesome

Comment: how can we refer storage account name while creating connection, it does not allow either accountName or storageAccountName ?